# form closing event in multiple windows form application using visual c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a multiple windows form application (frmMian, frmSteg and frmCrypt) in c#. From the main form (frmMain), I can call the other (two) forms. How can Iuse the form closing event similar to that used in VB to return to the main form whenever I exit any of the two forms?

```
 FrmSteg frmstego = new FrmSteg();
    FrmCrypto frmcrypt = new FrmCrypto();

    private void btnsteg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmstego.Show();
        this.Hide() ; 
    }

    private void btncrypto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmcrypt.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Form.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) event on the child windows.

```
frmstego.Closed += (s, e) => {
    this.Show();
};

frmcrypt.Closed += (s, e) => {
    this.Show();
};
```

Comment: the code gives this error:A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else. Any idea why

Comment: @suleimankurawa, yes, probably because you've pasted the code into another method that declares a variable called `e`.  If that's the case, just change `e` above to `e2` or whatever to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a Singleton accessor on the main form like this. And then in the constructor of the main form set `_instance = this`.

```
private static <MainFormType> _instance;

public static <MainFormType> Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ErikDietrich Primarily because as the application grows you are unable to ensure that the main form will become the selected form when closing the prior ones. Another option would be to ensure that the main form was the Parent of those other forms but it wasn't indicated that he was doing that.

Comment: @mperrenoud03 I dont really understand your explanation